# Changed SSH port from 22 to 1234, but port 22 still shows when I run nmap?

Tags: firewall, centos7

I used this article to change my ssh port on a centos 7 box:

https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/11/change-openssh-port-centos-7/

(I skipped the selinux stuff as I don't have that installed):

But when I run nmap on another server pointed at the centos 7 box it gives:

```
Host is up (0.00023s latency).
Not shown: 65533 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  closed ssh
1234/tcp  open   unknown
```

I tried

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --remove-port=22/tcp
```

but that gave me

```
Warning: NOT_ENABLED: 22:tcp
success
```

What am I misunderstanding here?  How can I make port 22 not show up on nmap?  Or *should* it still show up for some reason?

Comment: When your link goes dead, this question and all the answers will become useless. Insert your configuration within your question instead.

Comment: `22/tcp` **`closed`**

Comment: Great, but it doesn't also say `11/tcp closed`, or `12/tcp closed`.  I'm not saying it's a security risk of any sort, but it seemed odd to me that an un-used port was still being detected at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With firewalld on Centos 7 ssh is set via a service name and not via a port.

If you do a

```
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

It will list the open services on your machine, like "dhcpv6-client ssh"

Run the following to remove the service, add a permanent rule for your new ssh port and reload the firewall rules and then scan the machine again

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --remove-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=1234/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

You can leave out the "--permanent" part if you are unsure and the settings will be discarded after a reboot.

Comment: Just to be clear (and I'm sure you wouldn't suggest it if it WOULD), but this won't cause a problem and stop me from being able to use ssh, presumably...?

Comment: ssh is listening on your new port, I have modified my answer a bit.